# Explain an experiment: airstream between two hinged curved surfaces

Tags: experimental-physics, aerodynamics

Please, see the following video (the experiment starts at 3:40 and ends at 3:55):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pB6q_bH35s&feature=youtu.be&t=216

The basic idea: given 2 curved surfaces handing in 5cm to each other.
In the first part of the experiment, air is sucked through the surfaces with a vacuum cleaner, these surfaces start pulling each other and finally close up.

In the second part of the experiment, air is blown against the surfaces from a fan. And surfaces pull each other and close up again.

While the 1st part looks pretty natural (there must be a low pressure area between the surfaces), the 2nd part looks surprising to me.

Please explain these experiments.

Answer (score 0):

That's the [*venturi effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect).

There's a nice Khan Academy video [*here*](https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/mcat/physical-processes/fluids-in-motion/v/venturi-effect-and-pitot-tubes).